# How prove this Ratio Test and Its Generalizations problem?

Tags: analysis

**Question:**

> let $\alpha\in (0,1)$,and the postive sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ such
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\inf \left(n^{\alpha}\left(\dfrac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)\right)
> =\lambda\in (0,+\infty)$$
>
> show that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^k a_{n}=0,k>0$$

maybe  this is Ratio Test and Its Generalizations?

This problem is  The Chinese Mathematics Competitions 2014  before,But I can't prove it.can you help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mu\lt\lambda$, $\mu$ positive, then, for every $n$ large enough, say, for every $n\geqslant k$, $$n^{\alpha}\left(\frac{a_{n}}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)\geqslant\mu,$$ hence $$a_{n+1}\leqslant a_n\,\left(1+\frac{\mu}{n^\alpha}\right)^{-1}.$$ This implies that $a_n\leqslant C/b_n$, where $$b_n=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(1+\frac{\mu}{i^\alpha}\right).$$ For every $x$ small enough, $1+x\geqslant\mathrm e^{x/2}$ hence, for every $n$ large enough, $$b_n\geqslant C'\exp\left(\frac\mu2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{i^\alpha}\right)\geqslant C'\exp\left(\frac\mu2\int_1^{n+1}\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^\alpha}\right)\geqslant C''\exp\left(\frac\mu2\frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}\right).
$$ Finally, there exists $c$ and $\nu$ positive such that, for every $n$, $$a_n\leqslant c\exp(-\nu n^{1-\alpha}),$$ and this suffices to conclude.

Comment: nice +1! Btw, you forget the minus in the last inequality

Comment: @PetiteEtincelle Thanks. Yes.